# CSS Background / Border

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with my background, it will not go behind the border image.

I want the `.section` div background to go full width of the info-box and border, i.e. behind the border of the `.info-box` div.

I put it on fiddle so you can see what it is currently doing: https://jsfiddle.net/gof6yrrL/1/

HTML

```
<div class="info-box">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="spacing"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.info-box {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border: 18px solid transparent;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://goo.gl/sMJorg) 18 round;
    -o-border-image: url(http://goo.gl/sMJorg) 18 round;
    border-image: url(http://goo.gl/sMJorg) 18 round;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.section {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #103b49;
    background: #0a2629 url(http://goo.gl/K3oEje) top center repeat-x;
}
.spacing {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

The border has an inner shadow on the content below it, hence why I want the background to be behind it.

Comment: I don't understand. Please add an image of the desired behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the `.section` div cannot directly extend underneath the border of its parent element like you are looking for, because the border is part of the parent, and the child elements can either be above or below that, but not both.

What I would recommend you do instead is to make a new div that overlays your current div, that contains the border, but has `pointer-events: none;` set so that you can still click through to your content:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gof6yrrL/3/

```css
.info-box {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.section {
    height: 300px; 
    width: 100%; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #103b49; 
    background: #0a2629 url(http://goo.gl/K3oEje) top center repeat-x;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.spacing {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.info-box-border {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 18px solid transparent;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://goo.gl/sMJorg) 18 round;
    -o-border-image: url(http://goo.gl/sMJorg) 18 round;
    border-image: url(http://goo.gl/sMJorg) 18 round;
    border-radius: 5px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-box">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="spacing"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="info-box-border"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1 more small question, how do ya make it so .section auto increases height depending on the content. I've tried 100% and auto and not the desired effect. thanks